# LinkedList produces a huge delay on add()

Tags: java, linked-list, delay, lag

I've been working on a little proof of concept game that has a rolling environment in the background (2D). I have a custom class object called roadTile, which basically is a 200px tall block with a picture to paint on and some physics. I'm storing the tiles in a LinkedList 5 at a time. I have a main loop that is responsible for moving everything and checking for collisions. The loop is supposed to be performed every 50ms (controlled by a timer) and it keeps the rate fixed by measuring the length of the last run and then taking deducting it from the sleep-time.

This usually runs fine and the loops run in less than a millisecond, but when I start the program, it "chokes" after the first 2-7 times. I removed the old tile and put a new one on the bottom of the list. On calling the add (new roadTile()), the program halts for 20-400ms which is a millenium in computer time, and to top this off, the behavior isn't consistent. Sometimes it works fine some times not.

I'm pretty clueless how to eliminate this, any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried profiling your application? Most IDE have some nice tools for this (e.g. Netbeans). And don't now the actual size of your objects - but it might be the gc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you cache everything before you start working with graphics. This might be the cause of your delay.

Comment: i'm rather new to programming, could you clarify?

Comment: You are new to programming, yet you've made a game..? Are you sure you know what you are doing here? Caching your content means that the things you need to use have been placed in Memory beforehand instead of at runtime. The JVM got a "warm-up time" in which making a repetitive task might take longer the first couple of times before it kicks into gear.

Comment: Well I use the term "game" very loosely as this is just a jframe, Jpanel, bunch of keybindings and couple classes of logic. And no, I'm pretty sure I don't fully know what I'm doing, but the whole point of this attempt is to learn..

Comment: I understand that you want to learn, but maybe you should tackle less complicated things first. :)

Comment: As for the caching, I place the tiles in the list in the constructor of my main "engine" class which shortly after that starts repeating the main loop. is this wrong?

Comment: Yeah I know but as I'm studying by myself I really don't know what those less complicated things are.. my method is to try things out and learn new thing as challenges emerge.

Comment: Lemme give you a zip file. I used these things the first ½ year at my study :) It should be a piece of cake to learn it using this! http://tinyurl.com/9hw9zp7

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18007/discussion-between-tru7h-and-vipar)